# Android "WIN DEATH" without warning

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, native-activity

I get the following statements from logcat, just after some successful log statements indicating my application is doing just fine (stat output, etc...):

```
I/WindowState(  425): WIN DEATH: Window{4244e028 u0 com.stuffstuff.test/android.app.NativeActivity}
I/ActivityManager(  425): Process com.stuffstuff.test (pid 14142) has died.
W/ActivityManager(  425): Force removing ActivityRecord{41f17208 u0 com.stuffstuff.test/android.app.NativeActivity}: app died, no saved state
W/InputMethodManagerService(  425): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 14142 uid 10068
D/Zygote  (  122): Process 14142 terminated by signal (5)
```

What's different about every other question about this, is that there is always some log statements before this error.  Without warning, the window gets destroyed.

Any idea what would cause this?  Is there anything I can do to start tracking this down and debugging it?  I am using vs-android which uses gdb, and no faults occur.

If it matters, it's an OpenGL ES app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being related to a memory access issue.  In my particular case, I had an assignment operator that wasn't checking if the object was being set to itself.  This became applicable with my `Array<T>` class.